# Why ActiveStorage does not inherit from the database connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 database connections

my regular `ActiveRecord::Base`

and `MigrateFrom` defined like this:

```
class MigrateFrom < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  self.establish_connection :migrate_from
end
```

then I have a class with attachements in it like this

```
class MigrateTrack < MigrateFrom
    self.table_name = "tracks"
    belongs_to :migrateuser
    has_many :pictures, class_name: "MigrateTrackPicture", foreign_key: :track_id  
    has_one_attached :imported_file
end
```

If I request something like this:

```
MigrateTrack.find_by_id(MY_ID)
```

Request belongs to and will be run on my Database connection known as `migrate_from``

But if I request

```
MigrateTrack.find_by_id(MY_ID).imported_file.attached?
```

The request will be run on the regular `ActiveRecord::Base`

Why ? How can I change this behavior ?

Comment: Seems it's a normal behavior :( https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/38755

Answer (score 0):

My purpose behind this question was to duplicate Database entries related to `active_storage_attachments` and `active_storage_blobs`

So let's says I have 2 databases, one is the regular `ActiveRecord::Base`, and I set another database called `migrate_from`

My class will look like this:

```
module Migrate
  class MigrateFrom < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
    self.establish_connection :migrate_from
  end

  class Attachment < Migrate::MigrateFrom
    self.table_name = "active_storage_attachments"
  end

  class Blob < Migrate::MigrateFrom
    self.table_name = "active_storage_blobs"
  end
end

class TargetAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "active_storage_attachments"
end

class TargetBlob < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "active_storage_blobs"
end
```

Now to be able to synchronise or re-import `active_storage_attachments` I set this simple function:

```
def migrateAttachements(record_id, target_record_id, record_type)
  Migrate::Attachment.where(record_id: record_id, record_type: record_type).each do |attachment|
    existingBlob = Migrate::Blob.find_by_id(attachment.blob_id)
    # To avoid overlapping with real database attachment
    targetedBlob = TargetBlob.find_by_key(existingBlob.key)
    if targetedBlob.nil?
      targetedBlob = TargetBlob.create existingBlob.attributes.except("id")
    end
    attachment.blob_id = targetedBlob.id
    attachment.record_id = target_record_id
    TargetAttachment.create attachment.attributes.except("id")
  end
end
```